# RocksDB: when does CompactOnDeletionCollector trigger compaction?

Tags: rocksdb

When you are doing a large number of deletions (e.g. in a queue system), RocksDB wiki recommends using the `CompactOnDeletionCollector` to [speed up compaction](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Delete-A-Range-Of-Keys) and [reclaim deleted space faster](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Implement-Queue-Service-Using-RocksDB#reclaiming-space-of-deleted-items-faster).

The RocksDB code also has a comment that mention that the collector "marks a SST file as need-compaction", but it's not clear when the compaction will actually occur and how it's prioritized over regular compaction.

I'm configuring the collector this way:

```
options.table_properties_collector_factories.emplace_back(
                rocksdb::NewCompactOnDeletionCollectorFactory(10000, 7500, 0.5));
```

However, it's not clear when exactly the compaction should happen.

For example, I created a sample program to observe the compaction stats and SST file sizes with/without the collector factory but **I see no difference at all**:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <rocksdb/db.h>
#include <rocksdb/write_batch.h>
#include <rocksdb/options.h>
#include <rocksdb/utilities/table_properties_collectors.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    const std::string state_dir_path = "/tmp/typesense-data";
    system("rm -rf /tmp/typesense-data && mkdir -p /tmp/typesense-data");

    rocksdb::DB *db;
    rocksdb::Options options;
    rocksdb::WriteOptions write_options;

    // create the DB if it's not already present
    options.create_if_missing = true;
    options.write_buffer_size = 1*1048576;
    options.level0_file_num_compaction_trigger = 2;
    options.max_write_buffer_number = 1;

    // no difference when the following is commented out
    options.table_properties_collector_factories.emplace_back(
            rocksdb::NewCompactOnDeletionCollectorFactory(10000, 7500, 0.5));

    write_options.disableWAL = true;

    rocksdb::Status s = rocksdb::DB::Open(options, state_dir_path, &db);
    if(!s.ok()) {
        std::cout << "Error while initializing store: " << s.ToString() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        db->Put(write_options, "RL_" + std::to_string(i), "HELLO123HELLO123HELLO123HELLO123");
    }

    std::cout << "Deleting keys..." << std::endl;
    db->DeleteRange(rocksdb::WriteOptions(), db->DefaultColumnFamily(), "RL_", "RL`");
    std::cout << "Done deleting keys..." << std::endl;

    std::string stats;
    db->GetProperty("rocksdb.stats", &stats);
    std::cout << "Stats: " << stats << std::endl;

    delete db;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CompactOnDeletionCollector works on DB::Delete() operations and has no effect on DB::DeleteRange(). Also, it only triggers after an SST file is created. Users might need to either wait it to naturally happen, or trigger a Flush() to speed it up.

Comment: Got it. Assuming we are dealing with single delete operations, when you say, "wait it to naturally happen", can you please elaborate whether any kind of compaction prioritization happens using this factory, compared to not using it? Does the prioritization happen only once a compaction begins or does it trigger a compaction earlier?